# Changes in default Property pane using SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, property

Can we change default property pane using SPFX extension ? like hiding or removing

```
     @override
      public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
        const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
        if (compareOneCommand) {
          // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
          let newbutton: any = document.getElementsByClassName("od-DetailsPane-LegacySection")[0] || document.documentElement;  
          //newbutton.style.display='none';

          newbutton.hidden = event.selectedRows.length === 1;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Do you want to hide your custom command which you have added through SPFx extension?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i want to hide one metadata property which we get in right hand panel if we click on document